# Call stored proc with DateTime parameter in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is probably a simple question but I couldn't find the answer. I have a stored procedure that takes a DateTime parameter like so:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetSchedule]
(
    @theDate DATETIME,
    @teamId INTEGER
)
...
```

And I'm trying to call it like this:

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("spGetSchedule",
    new SqlParameter("theDate", DateTime.Now.Date),
    new SqlParameter("teamId", teamId));
```

I keep getting a message back telling me that parameter @theDate was not provided.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: new SqlParameter("@theDate", DateTime.Now.Date),  new SqlParameter("@teamId", teamId));

Comment: No I tried that as well, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names do need to contain the @.  Also need to include the param names in the command.

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("spGetSchedule @theDate, @teamId",
    new SqlParameter("@theDate", DateTime.Now.Date),
    new SqlParameter("@teamId", teamId));
    spGetSchedule @theDate, @teamId.
```